# Cannot connect to Apache from Android App, though it works from browser

Tags: android, httpclient

I've been trying to connect my Android app to my Apache server for the past two days with no luck.

A few things to note:

- I can connect to my server through web browser from every machine in
  the network (Firewall isn't blocking connections)
- My server is set up in a virtual machine
- I'm using port    8079 (because for some reason I cannot connect
  through port 80)
- I added "Allow from All" to these three "/etc/apache2/ports.conf" and the "conf file of the website" and "/var/www/"
- In my Android app, before this code, I used the connectivityManager class to check my connection and it works correctly (It's not included in the below code)

This is the Android code. I keep getting "caught exception" error.

```
public void tryConnection(View V) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://192.168.*.*:8079/?var=hi");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        if (response != null) {

            String line = "";
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            line = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            Toast.makeText(this, line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to get response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Caught ClientProtocolException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Caught IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Caught Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stream Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return total.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the emulator or a physical device? Also, print the stack trace and post it.

Comment: I tried both a physical device and the emulator, both give the same result. I edited the question and added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple!

I had to use AsyncTask to make it work. Thanks for tato.rodrigo for pointing the need to check the stack trace.